# Jade variable attribute names

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I have a variable called current which is used to set the `checked` value of an html input

so `current` can be either `''` (blank) or `checked=true`

Since you cant set HTML attributes to false, I can't do this:

```
input(checked="#{current}")
```

So, I need so use a variable as the entire attribute. Is this possible with Jade? Other than just writing the HTML string in there

Edit to be more clear. I want to do this:

```
someVar = "checked=true"    
input(somevVar) // <input checked="true">
```

Comment: Please have a look at my edited answer. That's how you do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jade supports boolean attribute](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#attributes) such as `checked` directly via this syntax:

```
input(type="checkbox", checked=current)
```

From the docs:

> Boolean attributes are also supported:
>
> input(type="checkbox", checked)
>
> Boolean attributes with code will only
>   output the attribute when true:
>
> input(type="checkbox", checked=someValue)

Make sure you are specifying the `!doctype 5` directive as well in your layout template.

Here's an example:

```
var jade = require('jade');

var templateFn = jade.compile('doctype 5\ninput(type="checkbox", checked=current)\n');
console.log(templateFn({current: true}));
console.log(templateFn({current: false}));
```

It outputs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><input type="checkbox" checked>
<!DOCTYPE html><input type="checkbox">
```

Comment: Yeah,but I want to set the _entire thing_ with a variable. HTML is weird where only the absence of the attribute will set it to false, I can't simple set someValue to false

Comment: Yes, I totally understand your goal. I believe jade supports this as I have described. Did you try it?

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I wanted. Really great feature of jade. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as such:

```
input(type='checkbox', id='IsPublic', name='IsPublic', value= model.IsPublic)
```

Where model.IsPublic is from the model passed in from your response in node.

In the above example it is backed with mongodb where the model looks like:

```
IsPublic: { type: Boolean, default: false}
```

in the above case there is a property that denotes public or not yours would be "current".

NOTE: don't be confused by "model" personally i pass in everything or the core properties as an object called "model" for consistency. In your case you may be passing in the property directly so don't be confused by that part just to clarify.

Comment: I want the _entire attribute_ to be a variable. Updated my Q to be more clear.

Comment: @Wes ahh!!! good edit, didn't catch that. can I ask why so as to understand better?

Comment: `- if (something) { current = "checked=true";} else {current=""}.`

HTML does not allow `checked=false`, otherwise I'd just set the value to false and move along with my life. Its the absence of the checked attribute all together which causes a checkbox to _not be checked_

Comment: hmm o.k. well if you pass a true or false prop and wire it up to the value it will auto show check or not checked based on that value. I can show you a live example. my point is unless you are trying to manipulate it in script or something there would be no reason to have to have that if statement in jade when it loads. What am I missing?